# compare current date and time and retrieve data from database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

in my database am storing fields such as name , comment and datetime(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM). When i try to retrieve the data using a select statement, it is not working and showing a null pointer exception the code for creating and inserting the database is

```
            SQLiteDatabase database;
            String st = yeartopass+"-"+monthtopass+"-"+daytopass+" "+hourtopass+":"+minutetopass;
            database = getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase(
                    "universalreminder", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            database.execSQL("create table if not exists birthdaytable(nameofperson varchar(20),comment varchar(150),bdatetime varchar(20));");
            database.execSQL("insert into birthdaytable values('"+name+"','"+comment+"','"+st+"');");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),st,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and this is the code where i try to select

```
  public class CustomDialog extends Activity{
SQLiteDatabase database;
TextView text;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    //              database.execSQL("select bdatetime from birthdaytable ");
            // Create custom dialog object
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CustomDialog.this);
            // Include dialog.xml file
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogwindow);
            // Set dialog title
            dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
            getname();
            // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
            text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1indialog);


            dialog.show();

            Button declineButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonindialog);
            // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            declineButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Close dialog
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });



}
public void getname(){
    final String TAG = "CustomDialog";
    int year, month, day, hour, minute;
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    String datetimecheck = year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" "+hour+":"+minute;
    try{
    database = getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase(
            "universalreminder", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), datetimecheck+" ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select nameofperson from birthdaytable where bdatetime = '"+datetimecheck+"';",null);
            // where bdatetime = '" + datetimecheck+"'",null );
            //("birthdaytable", new String[] {"nameofperson"}, "bdatetime = '" + datetimecheck+"'", null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToNext()){
        text.setText(cursor.getString(0));

    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e+ " ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
     }
```

when i print the exception it says java.lang.NullPoninterException

my log cat entry is

```
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142): java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142):   at com.universalremainder.CustomDialog.getname(CustomDialog.java:71)
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142):   at com.universalremainder.CustomDialog.onCreate(CustomDialog.java:34)
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
    04-20 11:29:26.690: E/CustomDialog(1142):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here s wats at line 71

```
     text.setText(cursor.getString(0));
```

and at line 34

```
     getname();
```

Comment: Log the exception instead of toasting it and post the stacktrace in your question.

Comment: Would appear that your cursor is null

Comment: @laalto how can i do that?

Comment: @TashPemhiwa is that a problem coz of wrong insertion?

Comment: For example, `android.util.Log.e("TAG", "", e)` in the catch block. Or just remove the try-catch altogether and let the exceptions propagate to the default handler which logs them for you.

Comment: @laalto : `e.printStackTrace()` is a better way for logging exceptions.

Comment: @laalto i still don't understand what the problem is

Comment: It is also possible that the `Calendar` instance you use in your `getname()` method is null.

Comment: If this is the line you are getting NPE, then, two things can be null: either your `text` or the string you are fetching by `cursor.getString(0)`. Find out which one is null, and act accordingly.

Comment: @XaverKapeller the calender instance is initialized

Comment: Well then look at line 71 in your CustomDialog.java file in the `getname()` method. This is were the NPE occurs. Tell us what is causing the exception and we can help you further.

Comment: @shree202  the variables `name comment and st` that am inserting into the database is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> here s wats at line 71
>
> ```
> text.setText(cursor.getString(0));
> ```

`text` is `null`.

There's not enough context to help you initialize it exactly, but probably something like

```
text = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.some_textview_id);
```

does the trick.

Comment: You should be doing it before `getname()` and not after.

Comment: it worked in a way, it removed the exception but am not getting any text in that textview